# Jquery Use toggle class with two elements

Tags: jquery, html, if-statement, addclass, toggleclass

I need a little tip here to solve this:

I have 6 buttons that, when user clicks on it, a 'data bar' fills up. This is done by changing the height of that databar div.

```
If user clicks on button1 or 2 -> Databar changes to small
If user clicks on button 3 or 4 -> Databar fills up to medium
If user clicks on 5 or 6 -> Databar fills to large
```

The problem is: I cannot use toggleClass to toggle the div to different height. Because with using toggle class method this will happen:
If user clicks on button 1, the div will be correctly changed to 'small'. However if user also clicks button 2, the class will be removed of course.
I would like the user to be able to click button 1 and 2, so that the div changes to 'small' class. However if user UNCLICKS button 1 AND 2...The 'small' class should be removed.

The same also applies for the rest of the buttons. So if user UNCLICKS both 3 and 4, the 'medium' class should me removed so that the div height goes back to zero, small or whatever other buttons are clicked.

I have created a fiddle to illustrate what i want:
http://jsfiddle.net/NvdB31/M6jGJ/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check whether or not one of the buttons is clicked and has the class `button_clicked`. Knowing this, you can then use `toggleClass` after all.

Change your JavaScript to the following:

```
$(".button1, .button2").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("button_clicked");
    var show = $(".button1, .button2").hasClass("button_clicked");
    $(".databar").toggleClass("databar_small", show);
});

$(".button3, .button4").click(function() {   
    $(this).toggleClass("button_clicked");
    var show = $(".button3, .button4").hasClass("button_clicked");
    $(".databar").toggleClass("databar_medium", show);
});

$(".button5, .button6").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("button_clicked");
    var show = $(".button5, .button6").hasClass("button_clicked");
    $(".databar").toggleClass("databar_large", show);
});
```

Update of your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M6jGJ/2/).

Edit: As a bonus I've updated the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M6jGJ/3/) once again, to be using less JavaScript and making use of just one button class instead of 6.

Answer (score 0):

Use `hasClass` function for check `class` exist or not if exist remove the class otherwise add `databar_small` class. Just like below code,

```
$(".button1, .button2").click(function() {
    if($(".databar").hasClass("databar_small")){
        $(".databar").removeClass("databar_small");
    }
    else{
        $(".databar").addClass("databar_small");
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("button_clicked");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pL2Z2/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. However this does not completely solve it. If user clicks button 1, the class is added. However if user clicks button 2 it should STAY on the previously added class. Now...it goes back to zero if user clicks button 1 AND 2.